# What is the procedure to participate a open source project?

Tags: open-source

I browsed some of their sites. They always point to bug list as start of participating project.But, as a newbie in that project? How can I fix bug at the beginning?

Can anybody give me some suggestions about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issac Truett's answer is good.

My only suggestion would be to pick a project and download their source code.  Most open source projects use CVS, Subversion, or Git to manage the source code.

Pick an integrated development environment (IDE) that supports the language of the project and attach the IDE to their source code manager.

Spend some time getting familiar with the source code, and the bug list will make more sense.

Comment: right, I think this is a so important step before I really Programming something. Thank you Gilbert.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every Open Source project I've ever seen has a stack of minor issues in the corner - cosmetic or otherwise largely inconsequential things that nobody has considered worth their time. If you just want to get your foot in the door, that's probably a good way to introduce yourself. Just find something easy, make sure you implement it well, and follow the project's rules on coding style, submission for review, etc.

Or, ask the project. "I'm new, I want to help, this is my skill set. Would someone be willing to mentor me?"